# How to set shared library path when deploy the application

Tags: c++, cmake, shared-libraries

Before, I preferred to use static library when deploying my application. But later I find it more convenient to use shared library since sometimes I can just replace the library instead of rebuilding the whole application.

One problem is that how to set the shared library path in the deployed environment. I know one way is to set `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, but for some reason I am not allowed to do it. Is there any way to do it within cmake? For example, in the deployed environment I put all shared libraries in folder `/app/lib`. Suppose that I put my executable file under the folder `/app/bin`. How should I set `RPATH` in cmake?

I tried

```
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "$ORIGIN/../lib")
```

But it still cannot find the shared library. Thanks for any help.

Comment: You can set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` on a per execution base, as an example: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/app/lib your_executable`. Are you allowed to do it?

Comment: Dollar sign in `$ORIGIN` should be escaped. See [that mailing](http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2008-January/019290.html) and choose escaping mechanism which works for your system.

Comment: @skypjack as mentioned, I am not allowed to do it.